# Transpositional Algebra: Isolating a whole number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this question where I think I can get the answer but there must be a simpler way.

> **Question:** If
>
> $$\frac{(2x)}{5} - 6 = \frac{(3x - 6y)}{10},$$
>
> solve for $x$.

First $$20x -60 = 15x-30y,$$

then $$5x = -30y +60.$$

The answer that I can't seem to get to properly is

$$x = 60 - 6y.$$

I need to somehow isolate the $60$ so it's not divided by $5$.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error occured at the very beginning between the first equation and the second.

When you cross multiplied the initial equation, you multiplied both sides by $5$ and $10$, but the $6$ on the left hand side was only multiplied by $10$. You should have

\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{2x}{5} - 6\right)\times 10\times 5 &= \left(\frac{3x - 6y}{10}\right)\times 10\times 5\\
\left(\frac{20x}{5} - 60\right)\times 5 &= (3x - 6y)\times 5\\
20x - 300 &= 15x - 30y.
\end{align*}

If you proceed from here, you will be able to obtain $x = 60 - 6y$ as desired.

Alternatively, you can see the issue another way by first writing the left hand side of your initial equation as a single fraction. That is,

$$\frac{2x}{5} - 6 = \frac{2x}{5} - \frac{6\times 5}{5} = \frac{2x}{5} - \frac{30}{5} = \frac{2x - 30}{5}$$

so the initial equation becomes

$$\frac{2x - 30}{5} = \frac{3x - 6y}{10}.$$

Crossmultiplying, one again obtains the equation $20x - 300 = 15x - 30y$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Great answer, so well explained!